# ctx object in document sets

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, jsom, ctx

I need to get to the `ctx` object when a user navigates to a `document set`. My code runs well on all other pages so far, but on document sets it seems random if the ctx is loaded or not. I was told in another post that using `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, 'sp.js');` would assure me that I had access to the loaded object, so I've tried that.

I also use the method `_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push` to execute my main function (which uses the executeordelay method inside it). I had better results with `_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push` than `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push`, as I understand the first will be executed later in the loading.

What I want to achieve is to make a breadcrumb, and the ones I've seen available doesn't have the functionality we need. So I set out to make my own and try to make it fit our needs, learning a lot more about SharePoint along the way. This is parts of my script that only runs randomly in document sets:

```
var haveContext = (ctx) ? true : false;
.........

if (haveContext) {
   if (ctx.rootFolder !== "" && ctx.listUrlDir != ctx.rootFolder) {
   var startRootFolder = decodeURIComponent(ctx.rootFolder),
       startRootFolder = startRootFolder.replace(decodeURIComponent(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl), ""),
       rootFolderParts = startRootFolder.split("/"),
       //....... more code
```

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: SharePoint online. Oops. I noticed just now that I had tagged sharepoint add-in, must have clicked the wrong tag. Was supposed to be sharepoint-online. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet after SP.js has loaded to get current context.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I thought it would be best to use the built in ctx object rather than creating a new instance. Would `var ctx = (ctx) ? ctx : new SP.ClientContext.get_current();` be a better approach? Or is it best practice to create a new context object whenever you work with JSOM (I'm not on the app-web now)?

Comment: This won't work as the `ctx` object in the host web is not the same as an instance of the ClientContext object. I thought it might be different in the host web since I've been working mostly with add-ins. Still, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you add more details regarding where in host web are you trying to get the context? And which context do you need - app web or host web?

Comment: I need the context from the page I'm on. This is a script injected to the pages head tag, so I'm in the host-web. In the ctx object SP gives us, I easily find information about the root folders, items, lists, view titles etc. on the current page, without sending a query to the server myself. I could use the URL to get some of this info, but not all of it. The thing that's bugging me is that it's only in document sets that the ctx object seems to be initiated with some sort of delay, so my script only works 50% of the time.

Comment: @Chris if you know the `ctx` object always will be created, can't you just use a setInterval and pool for the `typeof ctx === 'object'` or something?

Comment: It won't be created in places like site settings I think. Let me check. If not that's a good idea. Thank you

Comment: @Chris I was thinking more specific just inside document sets, not other places, just when you are using the page docsethomepage.aspx

Comment: @Anders Okey. I just need to tweak my code some then. I already have a regexp that finds the .aspx part from the url, so it shouldn't be that much work I guess. Takker og bukker.